# Print the contents of a list next to each other

Tags: mapping, format

I want to print the contents of a list and I am doing

```
(message "%S" mylist)
```

The result is

```
(#("/home/hagbard/ergomax.org" 0 7 (fontified t)) #("/home/hagbard/wordy-english.org" 1 7 (fontified t)))
```

How can I print just the values next to each other.  What possibilities for printing are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the list without 'text-properties' use `%s` instead of `%S`.
Or if you prefer to print it as a string then use `mapconcat`, e.g.:

```
(message (mapconcat #'substring-no-properties mylist " "))
```

Comment: Note that if some of the text contains format specifiers, your call to `message` will fail as there will be nothing to substitute them with.  Therefore, instead of `(message (mapconcat #'substring-no-properties mylist " "))`, one should write `(message "%s" (mapconcat #'substring-no-properties mylist " "))`.